# Syntax error: "(" unexpected when starting Tomcat from IntelliJ

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea

I am having trouble running my Tomcat server through IntelliJ.  This was working last week.  Every time I run, I get the following error:

```
/home/arthur/apps/apache-tomcat-9.0.16/bin/catalina.sh run
Disconnected from server
/home/arthur/apps/apache-tomcat-9.0.16/bin/catalina.sh: 1: eval: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

I have tried the following:

- A different Tomcat directory
- Changed permission on the tomcat directory
- Copied a known working Tomcat installation from a colleague
- Restarted my computer
- Tried starting Tomcat from the terminal.  This worked, but I want to understand why it's not working from IntelliJ.

Since last week, I have installed the latest security updates for my OS.

OS:  Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS

IntelliJ:  2018.3.4 (Ultimate Edition)

Tomcat:  7.0.85, 8.5.37, 9.0.16

Comment: OK, have you looked at the first line of the `/home/arthur/apps/apache-tomcat-9.0.16/bin/catalina.sh` file? Looks like it's been corrupted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a known bug in IntelliJ IDEA:

- [IDEA-206243](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-206243) Tomcat startup script fails to run for copied run configurations

You can apply the patch from [this comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-206243#focus=streamItem-27-3273866-0-0). This patch is for 2018.3.4 version. Future updates will already have the fix included.